# NSDate: Date lies between two dates

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdate

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *pastSevenDays = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:-7*24*60*60];
NSLog(@"7 days ago: %@",pastSevenDays);

NSDate *pastFourteenDays = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:-14*24*60*60];
NSLog(@"14 days ago: %@",pastFourteenDays);

NSDate *pastThirtyDays = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:-30*24*60*60];
NSLog(@"30 days ago: %@",pastThirtyDays);

NSDate *pastSixtyDays = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*24*60*60];
NSLog(@"60 days ago: %@",pastSixtyDays);

NSDate *pastNintyDays = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:-90*24*60*60];
NSLog(@"90 days ago: %@",pastNintyDays);
```

Log:

```
2013-08-05 21:47:11.684 Time[29542:c07] 7 days ago: 2013-07-29 07:00:00 +0000
2013-08-05 21:47:11.685 Time[29542:c07] 14 days ago: 2013-07-22 07:00:00 +0000
2013-08-05 21:47:11.685 Time[29542:c07] 30 days ago: 2013-07-06 07:00:00 +0000
2013-08-05 21:47:11.685 Time[29542:c07] 60 days ago: 2013-06-06 07:00:00 +0000
2013-08-05 21:47:11.685 Time[29542:c07] 90 days ago: 2013-05-07 07:00:00 +0000
```

How do you check to see if an NSDate variable is between two dates?. i.e.:

```
NSDate *dateToCompare = //a date in NSDate Format


if (dateToCompare is on or before pastSevenDays) && ( datetoCompare is after pastFourteenDays)
{
\\ Do the following 
}

if (dateToCompare is on or before pastFourteenDays) && ( datetoCompare is after pastThirtyDays)
{
\\ Do the following 
}

// and so forth...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this should do what you need.

```
if ([dateToCompare laterDate:pastSevenDays] == dateToCompare)
{
    // dateToCompare is less than 7 days ago
}
else if ([dateToCompare laterDate:pastFourteenDays] == dateToCompare)
{
    // dateToCompare is more than 7 days ago, but less than 14 days ago
}
else if ([dateToCompare laterDate:pastThirtyDays] == dateToCompare)
{
    // dateToCompare is more than 14 days ago, but less than 30 days ago
}
```

Comment: This is at least different from the answers to the "possible duplicate", but I would still prefer the straightforward `compare:`.